# Update time in extjs automatically

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I want to show current time on a window in my app which is written using Extjs 3. The time should be updated every one second but I don't know how to do this. this is my code:
Can anyone help me please?

```
function gettime(){
        var dt = new Date();
        dt = dt.format('h:i:s');
        return dt;
    };

var clock = { layout:'form', frame:false, region:'center', height:100, width:400,
items:[{id: 'currtime', xtype: 'displayfield',fieldLabel: 'Current Time'
,value:gettime()}]}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`TaskManager`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#) or the vanilla [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) function to run your updating code periodically.

**Edit**

Example:

```
// Keep a ref, in case you want to stop it later
var task = Ext.TaskMgr.start({
    interval: 1000
    ,run: function() {
        Ext.getCmp('currtime').setValue(gettime());
    }
});
```

Comment: can you give me an example? I used setInterval but it didn't work!

Comment: You can find examples in the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: @JohanHaest How did you get the idea that the example would not be scrambled in another version of the doc? Well done.

Comment: My bad, didn't see the version number there, still same principle. 
Here's the ExtJS 3 version: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.util.TaskRunner

Comment: @JohanHaest Funny, I didn't see it either. I was referring to the fact that the example formatting is broken in Ext4.2.0 and Ext4.2.1 doc, while it is not in the version you've linked. Updating my example for Ext3.4 then...

Comment: @JohanHaest " w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp ":this really works:) thanks.

Comment: @msh Taskrunner uses setInterval under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need it for every second, but rather every minute you can do something like the following where you would only grab the time when the minute changes:

```
(function startClock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var sec = now.format('s');
    var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();
    var task = function(dt) {
        // start the interval
        runner.start({
            run: function() {
                Ext.getCmp('currtime').setValue(gettime());
            },
        interval: 60000 // 1 minute
        });
    };

    Ext.getCmp('currtime').setValue(gettime()); // inital set time
    Ext.defer(task, (60 - sec) * 1000, this, [now]); // get the time on next minute change
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you, i used ExtJS ver 4.2.1

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
bodyPadding: 5,
width: 200,
title: 'Update Time in ExtJS',
items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'Time',
    id: 'txtTime',
    name: 'txtTime',
    xtype: 'textfield'
  }
],
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});

 Ext.TaskManager.start({
    run: function() {
        Ext.getCmp('txtTime').setValue(Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'H:i:s'));
    },
    interval: 1000
});

});
```